# Watir Integration tests with phantomjs not working with internet

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, integration-testing, watir-webdriver

The project I'm trying to do uses watir-webdriver and selenium-webdriver and phantomjs to write tests. And these tests go green while internet is not connected, but when internet is connected ,it gives a `net:timeout error`. What could be the possible reasons?

Comment: Sorry I meant the project I'm trying to maintain

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take time out for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). You might also want to read [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you provide your code? It is very hard to suggest without it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will (hopefully) yield good answers. And you should include the minimal amount of code that demonstrates your issue and what you've done to solve it..